# read content of a /proc file without direct sys_open

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I am learning linux kernel development and writing a syscall to interface with a proc file. What are the ways I could read the content similar to cat /proc/myfile but without directly opening the file?

Comment: "I could read the content similar to cat /proc/myfile but without directly opening the file" - I don't understand. What do you mean by reading a file without opening it?

Comment: Without having to execute sys_open on the proc file, but rather reading the content another way.

Comment: Aside from opening and reading the file, there is no *generic* way for extract content of a file under `/proc`. Taking into account how the specific file is defined, it *could* be possible to obtain its content in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how the file you want to read is implemented in the source and do the same in your syscall.